# Avoiding owerwriting of variable from provider in build on Flutter

Tags: flutter, build, setstate, overwrite

In my app I have a button to open a popup and when I open it I use provider to prepopolate some fields with values taken from sharedPrefs.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   provider = Provider.of<FilesProvider>(context, listen: false);

   if (!newColumn) {
     colTitle = "Edit column";
     directoryName = provider.dirsNames[colIndex];
   }

   return AlertDialog(
     title: Text(colTitle),
     content: new Column(
        ...
     )
   );
}
```

Inside the AlertDialog I change the content of directoryName variable using the setState()

```
setState(() {
  directoryName = "new name";
});
```

At the end of AlertDialog I have a button to save the new values in memory.

I'd like to:

1. Open the popup
2. Popolate the directoryName var with the value from the provider
3. Change the value (and see the new value)
4. Save the new value in memory so that when I reopen the popup I could prepopolate the var with the modified value

The problem is that when I use the setState to make the change the widget rebuilds itself (as it should be) but then it overwrite my new value with the value from provider and it gives the impression that I didn't make the edit.

The only way that I found to make this works is by adding a new boolean variable "fieldsEdited", that it starts on false and that I put on true in the same setState where I change the directory name. In the build of the widget I check it and overwrite the value only if is false.

```
   if (!newColumn && !fieldsEdited) {
     colTitle = "Edit column";
     directoryName = provider.dirsNames[colIndex];
   }
```

---

```
   setState(() {
     directoryName = "new name";
     fieldsEdited = true;
   });
```

This works but I'm wondering if it's the right way or if there is something better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, my advice would be this: set the value of the `provider.dirsNames[colIndex]` when you edit it in the alert dialog.

```
// somewhere here
setState(() {
  directoryName = "new name";
});
```

Try to keep as little variables in your UI widgets and move this responsibility to your provider. This way you can care less about something going wrong after `setState()` is called.
This is exactly what provider is made for: keeping your app state separated from your UI code.